# random line in file

Tags: language-agnostic

This question was given to me during an interview. The interview is long over, but I'm still thinking about hte problem and its bugging me:

You have a language that contains the following tools: a `rand()` function, `while` and `for` loops, `if` statements, and a `readline()` method (similar to python's [`readline()`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)). Given these tools, write an algorithm that returns a random line in the file. You don't know the size of the file, and you can only loop over the file's contents once.

Comment: Did they require a uniform distribution in the returned line? Because it would be trivial to do otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know the desired answer, but my solution would be the following:

```
chosen_line = ""
lines = 0

while (current_line = readline()):
    if (rand(0, lines) == 0):
        chosen_line = current_line

    lines++

return chosen_line
```

Edit: A good explanation why this works was posted in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784213/random-line-in-file/11784334#comment15653945_11784334).

Comment: This is what they were looking for. They wanted to see if you knew that the product of `(n/(n+1))` as `n` goes from `1` to `p` is `1/(p+1)`. (Provable by induction.)

Comment: If you don't see why the code above works, think it through this way: It takes the first line with probability 1. That's right for one line. On the second line, it switches to that line half the time, so half the time it has the first line, half the time the second, good so far. On the third line, it takes the third line 1/3 of the time. We already know half the remaining time it had the first line (1/3) and half the remaining time the second (1/3). So still good for three lines. And so on.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz +1 The explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One method, guaranteeing a uniform distribution:

(1) Read the file line-by-line into an array (or similar, e.g. python `list`)

(2) Use `rand()` to select a number between 0 and largest index in the array.

Another, not guaranteeing a uniform distribution:

Read each line. On each read, also call rand(). If over a threshold, return the line.

Comment: Well I didn't downvote but it's clearly inferior to the accepted answer which gets a uniform distribution without using an array. And arrays were not one of the language features the OP said were available.

Answer (score -1):

Although similar to Marcin's third option, Luc's implementation always returns the first line, while parsing the whole file.

It should be something like:

```
chosen_line = ""
treshold = 90 
max = 100

while chosen_line == "":
    current_line = readline()
    if (rand(0, max) > treshold):
        chosen_line = current_line

print chosen_line
```

You could also return current_line in the case no line was chosen and you read the whole file.

Comment: Luc's implementation doesn't always return the first line, and this one doesn't give a uniform distribution. -1.

Comment: Now I understand Luc's code. You are still parsing the whole file, but it's not described in the problem as something you should avoid.

Comment: There is no clue as to how long the file can be. It may be five lines, but also five million. To get any sort of randomness into it, you'll have to read the entire file to find out. Given capacity problems, you could limit how far it reads or so... But there is nothing about that in the question.

Comment: I also only put forward two methods.